# Cocoa - Frame External App in fullscreen?

Tags: cocoa, macos, frame, fullscreen

I was wondering if it was possible to "frame" an external Application Window in a fullscreen application, like [This](http://i1024.photobucket.com/albums/y301/Flafla2/Diagram.png).  If so, please provide a code example on how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OmniDazzle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnidazzle/) for example is able to create callouts around windows (and even UI elements) so yes, it is possible to get a windows´ position and dimensions and arrange your application around it without losing focus on it.

=== edited ===

I´ll provide some starting points for you, though I can´t write the complete code; but maybe someone else will find this useful. You´ll still need to find the position and size of the window you want to "frame" (or move this window to a desired position) and then have your window contain a transparent area that doesn´t respond to clicks.

Starting points to create a transparent window (Taken from [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?TransparentScreenSaver)):

```
[[self window] setOpaque:NO];
[[self window] setBackgroundColor: [NSColor clearColor]];
[[self window] setAlphaValue:0.999f];     
[[self window] setShowsResizeIndicator:NO];
[self lockFocus];
[[NSColor clearColor] set];
NSRectFill([self bounds]);
[self unlockFocus];
```

And to make the window ignore mouse clicks:

```
[[self window] setIgnoresMouseEvents:YES];
```

Comment: I do not have time to create the whole code for you, but I´ve edited my answer above to include some starting points, maybe that´ll help.